# Unable to display mp4 after process video opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video, mp4

I have this code

```
import cv2
from .inference import inference


def create_video_from_frames(frames, output_path, fps):
  # Get the dimensions of the first frame
  height, width, _ = frames[0].shape

  # Resize all frames to have the same dimensions
  resized_frames = [cv2.resize(frame, (width, height)) for frame in frames]

  # Create a VideoWriter object
  fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
  video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(filename=output_path,
                                 fourcc=fourcc,
                                 fps=fps,
                                 frameSize=(width, height))

  # Write each frame to the video file
  for frame in resized_frames:
    video_writer.write(frame)

  # Release the video writer
  video_writer.release()


def process_video(original_video_path, processed_video_path):
  # Open the video file
  capture = cv2.VideoCapture(original_video_path)
  fps = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
  width = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
  height = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

  # # Create a VideoWriter object to save the processed video
  # fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
  # writer = cv2.VideoWriter(processed_video_path, fourcc, fps, (width, height))

  # Process each frame of the video
  frames = []
  counter = 0
  try:
    while True:
      # Read a frame from the video
      ret, frame = capture.read()

      if not ret:
        break

      # Process Layers
      frame = inference(frame)

      # Write the processed frame to the output video
      # writer.write(frame)

      frames.append(frame)

      print(counter)
      counter += 1
  except:
    pass

  # Release resources
  capture.release()
  # writer.release()

  create_video_from_frames(frames, processed_video_path, fps)
```

It successfully processed video, I'm able to open the processed video with `Windows Media Player` but I'm not able to open the processed video with `web browser` such as Edge and Firefox.

I also check the validity of mp4 using this code

```
import cv2


def is_valid_mp4(file_path):
  try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
    is_valid = cap.isOpened()
    cap.release()
    return is_valid
  except:
    return False


print(is_valid_mp4('static/tmp/original_video.mp4'))
print(is_valid_mp4('static/tmp/processed_video.mp4'))
```

It returns true.

Note that, original_video is able to open with web browser while processed_video is unable.

I also check size of frames of video and all are same

```
import cv2

# Open the video file
video_path = "static/tmp/processed_video.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Check if the video file was opened successfully
if not cap.isOpened():
  print("Error opening video file")
  exit()

# Iterate through the frames
frame_number = 0
while True:
  # Read the next frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()

  # Check if frame was successfully read
  if not ret:
    break

  # Increment the frame number
  frame_number += 1

  # Try to decode the frame
  try:
    # Convert the frame to grayscale for simplicity
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  except cv2.error as e:
    print(f"Corrupt frame at frame number {frame_number}")
    print("Error:", e)

# Release the video capture object and close any open windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So what's wrong this?

Comment: mp4v is mpeg4 part 2. Can you check what exact codec your original video was? Probably you will need AVC codec. See https://superuser.com/a/118737/395388

Comment: Micka is correct. For better compatibility, you may create `.mkv` video file, and rename it to `.webm`. AVC (H.264) codec (`VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')`) may require downloading openh264 DLL (at least in Windows). You may use VP8 codec `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'VP80')` with `.mkv` video file, and rename the file to `.webm`.

Comment: perhaps these browsers simply don't have a codec for that format. that's not an opencv problem then. please run `ffprobe` on the video file to verify.

Comment: `VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')` Fix my issue, thanks!